# Run Escalated(Admin) command window here from context menu

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator, context-menu

Would like to add a shortcut to launch the command window here from the context menu similar to the existing shortcuts for win7-10 and wanted it to run with admin priveleges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](http://michaelcrump.net/power-tip-elevated-command-prompt-here-in-windows-8-1/)

Open Notepad and copy-paste this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"HasLUAShield"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"HasLUAShield"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

Save as "addlink.reg" or similar (with File Types set to "All Files"), then double click on the file to add to the registry.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Honestly the ALT+F+M+A shortcut he mentions is fast enough for what I needed. I wasn't aware of the option in the explorer file menu for elevated privileges. Thanks for the more in depth answer though.